# Best way to handle (or) avoid too many "TCP_CLOSE_WAIT" state?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, httpurlconnection

What is the reason for too many tcp close wait state in my server and how could i resolve this?

This is the sample snippet which my java client invokes to connect with server

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(serverUrl).openConnection());
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
    os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

     //Write to output stream
    os.flush();
    os.close();

    urlConnection.connect();
    is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String eachLine = br.readLine();
    while (eachLine != null && "".equals(eachLine) == false) {
      sb.append(eachLine);
      eachLine = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
    is.close();
    return sb.toString();
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException se) {
             System.out.println("Socket time out exception ");
    } catch (Exception ioException) {
             System.out.println("IO Exception ");
    } finally {
       try {
        if (br != null) br.close();
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.toString();
       }

      try {
        if (is != null) is.close();
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.toString();
      }

      try {
       if (os != null) os.close(); 
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
       ioe.toString();
      }
    }
```

The following [article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/http-keepalive.html) suggests about keep-alive time and I could associate this with my client code which tries to connect it with the server.

The client can read error stream completely when exception occurred so that the underlying tcp connection could be reused.

When could I get too many tcp close_wait state and how can I avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean by "too many"? This is a normal part of the connection shutdown process.  If you're seeing these on the server it means the client went away without completing the close process.

Comment: @JimGarrison No it doesn't. It means the server ignores client disconnections. The local TCP has received a FIN and is waiting for the local application to close. And one is too many. There shouldn't be any ports in CLOSE_WAIT state in a well-written server, except very transiently.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that your server code is not actively closing client connections by calling close(), leaving sockets in a state known as "half-closed".

To fix this issue, your server should detect when the connection was closed by the remote host and close the connection appropriately. If you fail to do this connections will stay in the CLOSE_WAIT state until the process itself is terminated and the OS closes all existing connections.

TCP connections actually consist of two half-connections which can be closed independently of each other. One end (like A in diagram below) can call `close()` on the socket, signaling that it will not send any more data, but the other end (like B in diagram below) may just ACK and continue sending data to A.

```
(A calls close())
A -----FIN-----> B
FIN_WAIT_1       CLOSE_WAIT
A <----ACK------ B
FIN_WAIT_2

(B can send more data here, this is half-close state)

(B calls close())
A <----FIN------ B
TIME_WAIT        LAST_ACK
A -----ACK-----> B
|                CLOSED
2MSL Timer
|
CLOSED
```

Comment: 'Most probably'? What other cause could there be?

Comment: @EJP I don't know any other reason really, was just wording. Will edit to be more precise.

Comment: It's not a question of knowledge. My point is that there *can't* be any other reason, by definition. It means exactly one thing.

Comment: Understood. I am aware that can't be any other reason so I reworded my answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the reason for too many tcp close wait state in my server and how could i resolve this?

Your server is leaking sockets. It is failing to detect client disconnects, or ignoring them, and not closing the socket.

The link you cite is irrelevant.